# CollectionView and UISegmentedControl error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a little problem in my code, I use a CollectionView with segmentedControl but here when I press section 2 or 3 of segmetedControl and I scroll the CollectionView, I get this error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 16 beyond bounds [0
>   .. 15]'

```
#define API_V3_CHANNEL_URL @"examples.json"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self fetchEntries];
    [self fetchEntriesWinner];
    [self fetchEntriesPhotos];

}

- (void)fetchEntries
{
    NSString *searchURL = [API_V3_CHANNEL_URL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *searchData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchURL]];
    NSDictionary *searchDict =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:searchData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    //self.readArray = [searchDict objectForKey:@"CONTESTS"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %@", @"LIVE"];
    self.readArray = [[searchDict objectForKey:@"CONTESTS"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    NSLog(@"%@", self.readArray);

}

- (void)fetchEntriesWinner
{
    NSString *searchURL = [API_V3_CHANNEL_URL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *searchData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchURL]];
    NSDictionary *searchDict =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:searchData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    //self.readArray = [searchDict objectForKey:@"CONTESTS"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %@", @"ARCHIVED"];
    self.readArrayWinner = [[searchDict objectForKey:@"CONTESTS"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    NSLog(@"winner array : %@", self.readArrayWinner);

}

- (void)fetchEntriesPhotos
{
    NSString *searchURL = [API_V3_CHANNEL_URL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *searchData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchURL]];
    NSDictionary *searchDict =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:searchData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    //self.readArray = [searchDict objectForKey:@"CONTESTS"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %@", @"LIVE"];
    self.readArrayPhotos = [[searchDict objectForKey:@"CONTESTS"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    NSLog(@"%@", self.readArray);

}

- (IBAction)segmentedControlAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    switch (_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            return [self.readArray count];
            break;

            case 1:
            return [self.readArrayWinner count];
            break;

            case 2:
            return [self.readArrayPhotos count];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"pictureCell";

    MSContestListCollectionViewCell *cell = (MSContestListCollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *searchResult = [self.readArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    NSDictionary *searchResult2 = [self.readArrayWinner objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    NSDictionary *searchResult3 = [self.readArrayPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    cell.titleContest.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.titleContest.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;

    cell.pictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    cell.pictureImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    cell.titleView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    cell.titleView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    switch (_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0: {
            NSString *stringImage = [searchResult objectForKey:@"featuredImage"];

            NSString *image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://srv.mediaswapp.com/%@", stringImage];
            [cell.pictureImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image]
                                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

            cell.titleContest.text = [searchResult objectForKey:@"description"];
            cell.statusContest.text = [searchResult objectForKey:@"status"];
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            NSString *stringImage = [searchResult2 objectForKey:@"featuredImage"];

            NSString *image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://srv.mediaswapp.com/%@", stringImage];
            [cell.pictureImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image]
                                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

            cell.titleContest.text = [searchResult2 objectForKey:@"description"];
            cell.statusContest.text = [searchResult2 objectForKey:@"status"];
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            NSString *stringImage = [searchResult3 objectForKey:@"featuredImage"];

            NSString *image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://srv.mediaswapp.com/%@", stringImage];
            [cell.pictureImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image]
                                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

            cell.titleContest.text = [searchResult3 objectForKey:@"description"];
            cell.statusContest.text = [searchResult3 objectForKey:@"status"];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move the following three lines inside the switch case:

```
NSDictionary *searchResult = [self.readArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
NSDictionary *searchResult2 = [self.readArrayWinner objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
NSDictionary *searchResult3 = [self.readArrayPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
```

It should be

```
switch (_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0: {
        NSDictionary *searchResult = [self.readArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        NSString *stringImage = [searchResult objectForKey:@"featuredImage"];

        NSString *image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://srv.mediaswapp.com/%@", stringImage];
        [cell.pictureImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image]
                                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

        cell.titleContest.text = [searchResult objectForKey:@"description"];
        cell.statusContest.text = [searchResult objectForKey:@"status"];
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        NSDictionary *searchResult2 = [self.readArrayWinner objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        NSString *stringImage = [searchResult2 objectForKey:@"featuredImage"];

        NSString *image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://srv.mediaswapp.com/%@", stringImage];
        [cell.pictureImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image]
                                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

        cell.titleContest.text = [searchResult2 objectForKey:@"description"];
        cell.statusContest.text = [searchResult2 objectForKey:@"status"];
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        NSDictionary *searchResult3 = [self.readArrayPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        NSString *stringImage = [searchResult3 objectForKey:@"featuredImage"];

        NSString *image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://srv.mediaswapp.com/%@", stringImage];
        [cell.pictureImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image]
                                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

        cell.titleContest.text = [searchResult3 objectForKey:@"description"];
        cell.statusContest.text = [searchResult3 objectForKey:@"status"];
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
}
```

The reason is that when `readArray` contains 16 elements and you try to display the section for `readArray` you will also try to access the `readArrayWinner` at index 16 which might not present since that array is smaller.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, I just have one last problem, when I click on a cell, nothing happens, and when I click on a second cell that displays the data of the previous cell (or the one I clicked on first) in resumé I think it shows me the wrong index.item (in the detail view)

Comment: @victorbill that is a different question since it has nothing to do with your current problem. If you cannot track down the problem on your own you can try to ask a second question regarding exactly that.

Comment: link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949499/click-collectionviewcell-error

Answer (score 0):

Array contain 16 object and you going to find objectAtIndex "16", it mean you finding 17th object in array which not available, so Terminating app with uncaught exception 'NSRangeException'.